# Как заархивировать несколько файлов?

Tags: python, zip

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

name = input("Название архива")
name = name + ".zip"
zipObj = ZipFile(name, 'w')
path = input("путь")
path2 = input("путь")
list_files = [path, path2]
zipObj.write(list_files)
print("done!")
zipObj.close()
```

Comment: zipObj = ZipFile('sample.zip', 'w')
zipObj.write('test_1.log')
zipObj.write('test_2.log')
zipObj.close()

Answer (score 0):

Метод [ZipFile.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) не принимает список, поэтому нужно самостоятельно перебрать список:

```
...
list_files = [path, path2]
for f in list_files:
    zipObj.write(f)
...
```

Но, в вашем примере список и не нужен:

```
...
zipObj.write(path)
zipObj.write(path2)
...
```